# Dynamic VBA Delete based on cell not containing Part of a text

Tags: vba, dynamic, delete-row

Trying to do a dynamic row removal for values in Column C where they value does not contain CY*. I have the below code but keep getting a If Block Error.  Anyone know how to make this work?

```
Dim ContainWord As String
On Error Resume Next
Range("C2:C" & lrow).Select
ContainWord = "CY*"
If Not Cell.Find(ContainWord) Then ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete.Row
End If
```

lrow is defined earlier in my code as:
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use autofilter and then delete visible cells

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim lRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("A1:Y" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>CY*"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
     .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With      
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution for what I am trying to do but I keep getting an error with it.  Do you know how to trouble shoot this one?

Comment: The auto filter Field & Criteria line generates the below error:

Comment: "The Command could not be completed by using the range specified. Select a single cell within the range and try the command again.

Comment: No I have 25 columns

Comment: The last row can be variable from month to month but never the columns

Comment: Try .Range("A1:Y" & lRow)  assuming data starts in column A and ends in Y.

Comment: Thank you that worked!!!! Changed my Range and everything is functioning.  makes sense now that you pointed it out.

Comment: AutoFilter is way faster than any other method +1. On the other hand, - toggling  ScreenUpdating  might slow it down a fraction of a sec, enough for some minimal flickering, when is not necessary)

Comment: @paulbica Thanks. Removed comment. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, finding the cell does not mean it's the active cell.

For Any cell in sheet

```
Public Sub Test()
 Sheet1.Cells.Find("CY*").EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Your Case (Just checking Column C up to row lrow)

```
Public Sub Test()
 ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & lrow).Find("CY*").EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be good for small datasets. If you are using a larger set autofilter would be faster.

```
     With ("C2:C" & 1row)
        Do
        Set rngFind = .Find(What:="CY*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        rngFind.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that I Just tested. It will work for multiple sheets, modify to suit your needs.

```
Sub FindCY()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim CYFind As Variant
CYFind = "CY*"

On Error Resume Next
For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Set Rng1 = WS.Range("C1").EntireColumn
For Each cell In Rng1
If cell.Value = CYFind Then
Rng1.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next cell
Next WS

End Sub
```